# How to use the exam package to have multicolumn with numbers across?

Tags: multicol, exam, parts, questionnaire

I'm trying to write a group of questions, like they look like in a textbook. Using the multicol package, I have been able to write it, but instead of doing

> ```
> a  e
>
> b  f
>
> c
>
> d
> ```

I want

> ```
> a b c d 
>
> e f
> ```

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[addpoints ,class=exam, crop=false]{exam}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage{multicol}
% Usage: \Problem{n}{operation}{m}
\newcommand\Problem[3]{$\begin{array}[t]{r}#1\\#2#3\\\hline\quad\end{array}$}


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question[30] Write as a power of 2
\droppoints

 \begin{multicols}{5}
 \begin{parts}
 \part 8
 \part 32
 \part $8^2$
 \part $4^3$
 \part $16^{-4}$ 
 \part $\frac{1}{2}$
 \part 32$^{\frac{2}{3}}$ 
 \part $64^{\frac{3}{2}}$
 \part 4$^x$     
 \part 8$^{2x}$  
 \part 128$^{-4x}$   
 \part 4$^{\frac{2x}{3}}$ 
 \part 16$^{-\frac{4}{3}x}$ 
 \part 16$^{x+1}$ 
 \part 4$^{2x-3}$ 
 \part 64$^{2-5x}$ 
 \part $8^{3x-1}$        
 \part 32$^{\frac{1}{x}}$ 
 \part 4$^{\sqrt{x}}$ 
 \part $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2x-6}$
 \end{parts}
 \end{multicols}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: what the code makes]

Comment: I suggest to try the `tasks` package, which does exactly the numbering you are looking for, and see if it is compatible with the exam class for your needs. (Citation: "The reason for the `tasks` environment is an unwritten agreement in German maths textbooks (especially in (junior) high school textbooks) to organize exercises in columns counting horizontally rather than vertically.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [benjamin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/93613/benjamin) suggested, the [tasks](https://ctan.org/pkg/tasks) package is useful, but I was not able to use it under the `exam` `parts` environment. Omitting the environment works:

```
\documentclass[addpoints ,class=exam, crop=false]{exam}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{multicol}
% Usage: \Problem{n}{operation}{m}
\newcommand\Problem[3]{$\begin{array}[t]{r}#1\\#2#3\\\hline\quad\end{array}$}


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question[30] Write as a power of 2
\droppoints
 
 \begin{tasks}[counter-format=(tsk[a]),label-width=4ex](5)
\task  8
\task  32
\task  $8^2$
\task  $4^3$
\task  $16^{-4}$ 
\task  $\frac{1}{2}$
\task  32$^{\frac{2}{3}}$ 
\task  $64^{\frac{3}{2}}$
\task  4$^x$     
\task  8$^{2x}$  
\task  128$^{-4x}$   
\task  4$^{\frac{2x}{3}}$ 
\task  16$^{-\frac{4}{3}x}$ 
\task  16$^{x+1}$ 
\task  4$^{2x-3}$ 
\task  64$^{2-5x}$ 
\task  $8^{3x-1}$        
\task  32$^{\frac{1}{x}}$ 
\task  4$^{\sqrt{x}}$ 
\task  $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2x-6}$
\end{tasks}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems not to work any longer. With TeX Live 2023 it results in overlapping of text `(tsk[a])` with the math expressions as shown in https://i.imgur.com/ZbcKz7W.png

Comment: To fix it, you have to use `label=(\alph*)` instead of `counter-format=(tsk[a])`. But also note, that using `inputenc` with option `utfx8` is not recommended, because it often breaks other packages like `hyperref`. Either use option `utf8` or remove loading `inputenc`, because it is not needed with LaTeX any longer. Also `hyperref` should be (almost) the last package not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better solution, however you could modify how you do your multicol allocation to the below to get the layout you want.

```
 \begin{parts}
 \begin{multicols}{5}
 \part 8
 \part 32
 \part $8^2$
 \part $4^3$
 \part $16^{-4}$ 
 \end{multicols}
 \begin{multicols}{5}
 \part $\frac{1}{2}$
 \part 32$^{\frac{2}{3}}$ 
 \part $64^{\frac{3}{2}}$
 \part 4$^x$     
 \part 8$^{2x}$  
 \end{multicols}
 \begin{multicols}{5}
 \part 128$^{-4x}$   
 \part 4$^{\frac{2x}{3}}$ 
 \part 16$^{-\frac{4}{3}x}$ 
 \part 16$^{x+1}$ 
 \part 4$^{2x-3}$ 
 \end{multicols}
 \begin{multicols}{5}
 \part 64$^{2-5x}$ 
 \part $8^{3x-1}$        
 \part 32$^{\frac{1}{x}}$ 
 \part 4$^{\sqrt{x}}$ 
 \part $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2x-6}$
 \end{multicols}
 \end{parts}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant using paracol.  Note that `\part` (`\item`) doesn't have an argument; it simply adds a label and starts a new paragraph.  `\mypart` however does.

The `\rule` in `\mypart` increases the spacing in an attempt to align baselines.  It works better than increasing `\itemsep`.

```
\documentclass[addpoints ,class=exam, crop=false]{exam}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter{numparts}
\globalcounter{partno}
\newcommand\mypart[1]{\part \rule{0pt}{1.5\ht\strutbox}#1\switchcolumn
  \ifnum\thecolumn=0\relax \switchcolumn[0]*\fi}% aligns tops, but not baselines

% Usage: \Problem{n}{operation}{m}
\newcommand\Problem[3]{$\begin{array}[t]{r}#1\\#2#3\\\hline\quad\end{array}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question[30] Write as a power of 2
\droppoints

\begin{paracol}{5}
 \begin{parts}
 \mypart{8}
 \mypart{32}
 \mypart{$8^2$}
 \mypart{$4^3$}
 \mypart{$16^{-4}$}
 \mypart{$\frac{1}{2}$}
 \mypart{32$^{\frac{2}{3}}$}
 \mypart{$64^{\frac{3}{2}}$}
 \mypart{4$^x$}
 \mypart{8$^{2x}$}
 \mypart{128$^{-4x}$}
 \mypart{4$^{\frac{2x}{3}}$}
 \mypart{16$^{-\frac{4}{3}x}$}
 \mypart{16$^{x+1}$}
 \mypart{4$^{2x-3}$}
 \mypart{64$^{2-5x}$}
 \mypart{$8^{3x-1}$}   
 \mypart{32$^{\frac{1}{x}}$}
 \mypart{4$^{\sqrt{x}}$}
 \mypart{$\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2x-6}$}
 \end{parts}
\end{paracol}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```